# Predict next numbers

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I would like to write script to predict the next numbers in a lottery. I downloaded a dataset and prepared it for using it with the script as shown below.

```
[[1, 3, 4, 20, 21. 12],
[44, 33, 22, 11, 10, 3] ...]
```

I also did a script which is using keras to predicate numbers but now I got an error 
'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)'. 
When I change Dense(6) to Dense(1) I get another error on line

`trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)`

> ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (4440,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (4440,6)'.

How I can resolve this problems to get 6 numbers? Is there a way to delete create_data_set? I found it but I don't even understand that. Maybe someone has an example with that type of problem where scripts have to predict some numbers

```
def create_data_set(_data_set, _look_back=1):
    data_x, data_y = [], []
    for i in range(len(_data_set) - _look_back - 1):
        a = _data_set[i:(i + _look_back), 0]
        data_x.append(a)
        data_y.append(_data_set[i + _look_back, 0])
    return np.array(data_x), np.array(data_y)

pathToFile = './dl.txt'
dataset = pd.read_csv(pathToFile, sep=' ', header=None, usecols=(1,2), names=['date', 'numbers'])
dataset = dataset['numbers'].values
parsedDataset = []
for i in dataset:
    parsedDataset.append(i.split(','))
dataset = parsedDataset
dataset = np.array(dataset)
dataset.astype('float64')

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train, test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.30, random_state=40)
train_x, train_y = create_data_set(train, 1)
test_x, test_y = create_data_set(test, 1)
print(train_x.shape[0])
train_x = np.reshape(train_x, (train_x.shape[0],1, train_x.shape[1]))
test_x = np.reshape(test_x, (test_x.shape[0], 1, test_x.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=3, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
trainPredict = model.predict(train_x)
testPredict = model.predict(test_x)

trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
train_y = scaler.inverse_transform([train_y])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
test_y = scaler.inverse_transform([test_y])
for i in range(testPredict.shape[1]):
        print("%.1f"%(testPredict[0,i]), end=' ')
print('\n',end="")
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to predict a random number?

Comment: My dataset has numbers from 1 to 40 and I would like to get numbers from this range

Answer (score 0):

Lottery numbers are true random if they are drawn in a traditional way with some kind of machine selecting balls in the real world, or even if not truly random multiple consecutive sets of lottery numbers do not have any connection, there are not dependent on one another in any way.

Your approach could be used to identify a possible continuation of a given series of numbers or something alike (as there is some "rule" to it which, with a big enough dataset could probably be figured out). 
But there is no (hidden) regularity to lottery numbers at all, so what you are trying to achieve appears rather impossible to me.

Answer (score 0):

First off this is an educational question stop looking at it as someone is asking you for the winning numbers.
simply put how do you write an LSTM to do prediction on multiple features.

1. The first problem, you are trying to predict six features but only select two columns "usecols=(1,2)"
2. The next problem, "def create_data_set" is made to be use with one column datset.